# How to highlight multiple words on VIM and modify them all? Like CTRL+D does on VS-Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, text, vim, editor, coding-efficiency

On VSCode, if you highlight a text, you can do "CTRL+d" and it will highlight the next matching text and add a cursor there.

You can then start typing/deleting and it will affect all the cursors.

How can I do this in VIM?

Note: I know the search and replace function, this is too slow to type, is there something as easy or almost as easy as it is on VSCode?

`:%s/foo/bar`

**Visual explanation on VSCode:**

1. Highlight the word you're looking to replace:

[image]

2. CTRL+d two times, which highlights them all:

[image]

3. Now modify them all at the same time:

[image]

Comment: The feature is called "multi-cursor" and there are already dozens of similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

I want this will help you.
You can do the below steps to change all selected words.

1. < SHIFT > + #  // select the all words on your cursor.
2. :%s//NEW_WORD/g

If you want to change all 'const' to 'AAA',
move to one of the 'const' words and press < SHIFT >+'#'.
And type the command ":%s//AAA/g".

Answer (score 2):

1. Move the cursor on top of a word in your code.
2. Type `gb` to add another cursor. This puts Vim into Visual
   mode and ready to operate on the word you have selected.
3. Type `gb` to continue adding cursors until you’re done.
4. Now you can perform an action in Visual mode (delete,
   change, etc).
5. Go back to Normal mode with `<ESC>`